# Best way to run a simple function on a new Thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, anonymous-function

I have two functions that I want to run on different threads (because they're database stuff, and they're not needed immediately).

The functions are:

```
            getTenantReciept_UnitTableAdapter1.Fill(rentalEaseDataSet1.GetTenantReciept_Unit);
            getTenantReciept_TenantNameTableAdapter1.Fill(rentalEaseDataSet1.GetTenantReciept_TenantName);
```

In javascript, I know I can create create an anonymous function and call it on a new thread quite easily with something like this:

```
setTimeout(new function(){doSomethingImportantInBackground();}, 500);
```

Is there something like this in C#?

Comment: Just an aside, but that Javascript code does **not** call a function on a new thread, it just schedules it to be run in the future.  Javascript is single-threaded, so all code runs on the same thread.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, I'm afraid. You can easily start a new thread with some code, using anonymous methods in C# 2, and lambda expressions in C# 3:

Anonymous method:

```
new Thread(delegate() {
    getTenantReciept_UnitTableAdapter1.Fill(
        rentalEaseDataSet1.GetTenantReciept_Unit);
}).Start();
new Thread(delegate() {
    getTenantReciept_TenantNameTableAdapter1.Fill(
        rentalEaseDataSet1.GetTenantReciept_TenantName);
}).Start();
```

Lambda expression:

```
new Thread(() =>
    getTenantReciept_UnitTableAdapter1.Fill(
        rentalEaseDataSet1.GetTenantReciept_Unit)
).Start();
new Thread(() =>
    getTenantReciept_TenantNameTableAdapter1.Fill(
        rentalEaseDataSet1.GetTenantReciept_TenantName)
).Start();
```

You can use the same sort of syntax for `Control.Invoke`, but it's slightly trickier as that can take *any* delegate - so you need to tell the compiler which type you're using rather than rely on an implicit conversion. It's probably easiest to write:

```
EventHandler eh = delegate
{
    // Code
};
control.Invoke(eh);
```

or

```
EventHandler eh = (sender, args) =>
{
    // Code
};
control.Invoke(eh);
```

As a side note, are your names really that long? Can you shorten them to get more readable code?

Comment: I think the OP wanted each call to Fill() to run on its own thread. But other than that, spot on.

Comment: @LBushkin: Will adjust. It's not a very clear question, to be honest.

Comment: I was going to expand my answer to include lambda's but yours is more complete (and better) anyway. A backgroundworker component is still an option, as you don't have to worry about Control.Invoke.

Comment: Okay, nevermaind, I don't have to execute it with Control.invoke. I thought it was earlier throwing an CrossThreadExecution thing-a-majigger

Comment: +1 for the comment on the long variable names with little to no actual meaning

Comment: Okay, I'll update the answer to keep the EventHandler stuff in, but in a slightly different way.

Comment: The names are correspond to the Stored Procedure, or the Table that they come from. I don't know why the '1' is appended to them.

Answer (score 30):

Similar to what's been said - I find tasks to be a bit simpler (supported as of [.net 4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task) and can be used as follows as of [.net 4.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.100))):

```
Task mytask = Task.Run(() => 
{
    //Lines of code
});
```

Comment: There is no Run method in .net 4

Comment: Correction made: tasks became available in .net 4 but the `Task.Run` syntax became supported in .net 4.5.

Answer (score 11):

Starting threads is relatively expensive.

You might be better of using a thread from the thread pool:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(unused =>
    getTenantReciept_UnitTableAdapter1.Fill(
        rentalEaseDataSet1.GetTenantReciept_Unit)
);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(unused =>
    getTenantReciept_TenantNameTableAdapter1.Fill(
        rentalEaseDataSet1.GetTenantReciept_TenantName)
);
```

Comment: How do you know when the threads are complete?

Ie. I did: `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(unused => data[0] = get_data(a,b));` `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(unused => data[1] = get_data(a2,b2));`

Comment: It's 2016 now. 'ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem' is so 2009. Use Tasks (see @JSideris) answer, or 'async'. Both provide ways to wait for the task to finish and retrieve a return value.

Answer (score 8):

You could use an anonymous method:

```
void Foo()
{
    Thread myThread = new System.Threading.Thread(delegate(){
              //Your code here
     });
    myThread.Start();
}
```

Comment: It gives error Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: @PrakashVishwakarma This is because you are accessing a Control element of your form, but on a different thread than the UI thread. You need to do textboxInput.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { Whatever(); })); and it will schedule the anonymous function () => { Whatever(); } on the UI thread.